# how to get 4.8 kernel in 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, kernel

After a fresh installation of 16.04.2, I still get 4.4 kernel as lots posted.
Read some posts from others, and ran command "apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04", I saw 4.10 kernel installed (latest one in HWE I guess), not 4.8 kernel I wanted.
How can I get just 4.8 kernel with 16.04.2?

Comment: Why do you think you need 4.8 specifically (instead of 4.10)?

Answer (score 1):

The 4.8 is not officially supported  for Ubuntu any more.

But you can still install any mainline kernel from [Ubuntu mainline kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline) at your own risk.

Comment: I think OP is simply trying to get a new kernel, the HWE (4.10) should do.

Comment: OP clearly stated that they don't want the 4.10 kernel.

Comment: probably read the question too fast ;)

Comment: We want to stick with 4.8 kernel, so we don't need to rebuild all local modified drivers against new kernel.

Comment: What I'm looking for here is a similar command to just upgrade kernel from 4.4 to 4.8, after installing 16.04.2.

Comment: There is no such command. You better stick to the 4.4 kernel as it is LTS for Ubuntu.